# HASS - usual method for getting sunrise and sunset time stopped working - how to solve it?

Tags: python, typeerror

I have this python program that I’ve been running on home assistant every day for over a year now.

It is called via shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 /config/solax/compute_pv_schedule.py $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6
```

Yesterday for the first time the script returned an error, which appears in the logs like this:

```
(...)
 File "/config/solax/compute_pv_schedule.py", line 331, in <module>
 v_sunrise_hour = int(v_sun.get_sunrise_time().strftime(\'%H\'))
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/suntime/suntime.py", line 34, in get_sunrise_time
 time_delta = self.get_sun_timedelta(at_date, time_zone=time_zone, is_rise_time=True)
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/suntime/suntime.py", line 131, in get_sun_timedelta
 UT += time_zone.utcoffset(at_date).total_seconds() / 3600
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: utcoffset(dt) argument must be a datetime instance or None, not datetime.date
```

The offending lines on the python program could not be simpler, and as previously said they have been working fine without any issue for over a year till now:

```
from suntime  import Sun, SunTimeException
(...)
v_sun          = Sun(k_latitude, k_longitude)
v_sunrise_hour = int(v_sun.get_sunrise_time().strftime('%H'))  ## <<<< offending line
v_sunset_hour  = int(v_sun.get_sunset_time().strftime('%H'))
```

As anyone seen this behavior as well?
It seems like something is broken in the underlying python libs, does it not?

Can anyone help here, some suggestion on how to fix this?
Or maybe we need a bug to be open on github?
Is this a known bug?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
-jprates

Comment: It looks like this a bug from the `suntime` module. There is an active issue on the [GitHub Page](https://github.com/SatAgro/suntime/issues/28). I would suggest that you +1 there with your error log and calling code. For now, you can fix your code by downgrading the version of `suntime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this looks like a bug in a commit from 3 days ago.  In the short term, you should be able to work around this by changing the code to:

```
now = datetime.now()
v_sunrise_hour = int(v_sun.get_sunrise_time(now).strftime('%H'))
v_sunset_hour  = int(v_sun.get_sunset_time(now).strftime('%H'))
```

### FOLLOWUP

I submitted a bug report.

Comment: Before anything else, thanks for taking the time to look into this, and for opening an issue for it.

Unfortunately your workaround however did not work:

`File "/config/solax/compute_pv_schedule.py", line 331, in <module><br/>`
`v_now = datetime.datetime.now() # workaround for python bug<br/>`
`^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^<br/>`
`AttributeError: type object \'datetime.datetime\' has no attribute \'datetime\'`

Comment: Ah, I should have seen they did `from datetime import datetime` instead of `import datetime`.  I'll patch my answer.

Comment: The developers tell me this problem has been solved in version 1.3.2.